# statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null Only developer Id can Login else error

Tags: android, google-play-services, google-signin

`GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN` allows only my developer id to log in otherwise, if I try to use other ids it is  throwing the error

> statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null

How can I sign in with other ids?

```
public void signin()
{  
 mGoogleSignInClient= GoogleSignIn.getClient(this,  GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN);


     Intent intent= mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();

       startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
  }


     @Override
          protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode==REQ_CODE)
    {

        GoogleSignInResult result= Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        handleResult(result);
    }
```

Error is 
        LoginResult: Status{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add Tester account in your Google Console for your project
See the following link for more.
https://developers.google.com/games/services/console/testpub
Thanks