# Unable to sign-in, statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED

Tags: java, android, libgdx, google-play-services, google-play-games

I'm trying to make the Play Game Services work, and for now, I'm trying a simple login attempt.
And for full two days, I'm stuck in the authentication stage.

I've followed the documentation and tried to link my app from scratch again.
double-checked my SHA-1 keys both the debug and the release. (there are two linked app in the Play Console). also checked that in the API Console everything is the same.
When I check the result from the sign-in attempt I see:
**statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED**.

Things that I checked or did:

> - SHA-1 keys
> - App Id correct and in the manifest
> - Correct Package
> - google-services.json downloaded
> - Link the app
> - Create a new app in the play console and new links
> - Firebase & Crashlytics is working
> - Enabled testing users

### From the APK:

[image: SHA-1 from the APK]

### From API console:

[image: API Console]

### Play Console:

[image: Play Console]

Silent Login:

```
    private void signInSilently() {
        GoogleSignInOptions signInOptions = GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN;
        GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(context);
    if (GoogleSignIn.hasPermissions(account, signInOptions.getScopeArray())){
        GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = account;
        Log.d("TEST_SILENT", "onComplete: " + signedInAccount);
    } else {
        final GoogleSignInClient signInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(context, signInOptions);
        signInClient
                .silentSignIn()
                .addOnCompleteListener(
                        activity,
                        new OnCompleteListener<GoogleSignInAccount>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    GoogleSignInAccount signedInAccount = task.getResult();
                                    Log.d("TEST_SILENT", "onComplete: " + signedInAccount);
                                } else {
                                    Intent i = signInClient.getSignInIntent();
                                    activity.startActivityForResult(i, 9001);
                                }
                            }
                        });
    }
}
```

Interactive Login:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 9001) {
        GoogleSignInResult res = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (res.isSuccess()) {
            Log.d("ASD", "onActivityResult: " + res.getSignInAccount());
        } else {
            Log.e("Asd", "onActivityResult: " + res.getStatus());
        }
    }
}
```

Added the APP ID

```xml
<meta-data android:name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID"
            android:value="@string/app_id" />
```

No matter what I do, I just can't get it to sign in.
And the status from the logcat is:

```
E/Asd: onActivityResult: Status{statusCode=SIGN_IN_REQUIRED, resolution=null}
```

Comment: ref:- [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37185464/googleapiclient-onconnectionfailed-with-statuscode-sign-in-required][1]

Comment: But I'm not using Drive API in the application...

Comment: Could be either an implementation or a configuration problem. If you use the gdx-gamesvcs lib to communicate with GPGS, you know for sure that the implementation is working. So just try using it.

Comment: Now I know about the gdx-gamesvcs lib, That's awesome. But I tried a simple test to connect and still not working. something in the configuration I guess - But I can't find what.

Comment: @DimaT. I'm in the same boat. Did you solve it?

Comment: unfortunately no, after a couple of days I released the game without the services since it was just a side project...

Comment: Please see this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54243804/statuscode-sign-in-required-resolution-null-only-developer-id-can-login-else-er.

Comment: did you eventually find a solution?